# how to compile (e.g. fail) a clojure file

Tags: clojure

I'm new to clojure.  I have defined a function in test.clj

```
(defn foldl [f val coll]
  (if (empty? coll) val
    (foldl f (f val (first coll)) (rest coll))))
```

I tried loading this file

```
user=> load-file "test.clj"
#object[clojure.lang.RT$3 0x16bb1d20 "clojure.lang.RT$3@16bb1d20"]
"test.clj"
```

It doesn't complain but when I try to use it

```
foldl + 0 (1 2 3)
```

I get

```
Syntax error compiling at (REPL:0:0).
Unable to resolve symbol: foldl in this context

#object[clojure.core$_PLUS_ 0x3df3a187 "clojure.core$_PLUS_@3df3a187"]
0
Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/eval2008 (REPL:1).
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

How do I force it to compile and tell me what's wrong with the function when I load it rather than when I execute it? Also what does the error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis when calling functions like `load-file` i.e.

```
(load-file "test.clj")
```

without parenthesis this just evalutes the symbol `load-file` which resolves to the function and the string "test.clj". Both of these are displayed in the REPL.

Similarly when calling `foldl`:

```
(foldl + 0 '(1 2 3))
```

in contrast

```
foldl + 0 (1 2 3)
```

is a list of 4 forms - the symbols `foldl` and `+`, the long 0 and the list `(1 2 3)`. Since you failed to load the file in the previous step, `foldl` cannot be found hence the error. `+` resolves to the `clojure.core/+` function which is displayed in the REPL. `0` evaluates to itself and is displayed in the REPL, while the list `(1 2 3)` is evaulated by attempting to call `1` as a function with arguments `2` and `3`. Since `1` does not implement `IFn` you receive the error "java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn".